# Programmatically create a UIView for UITabBarController

Tags: uiview, uitabbarcontroller

Hi i have a UITabBarController with 5 tabBar items.
The forth is UIScrollView.

The area that presented by the forth tab i wont to have specific height.

so till here i've done this

This is were i create my UITabBarController.(aViewController.h)

```
@interface aViewController: UIViewController <UITabBarControllerDelegate>{
UITabBarController *newTabBarController;
UIView *myView;
}
```

aViewController.m

```
- (void) viewDidLoad{
newTabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
newTabBarController.delegate = self;

myView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,self.view.frame.size.height - newTabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height)];
NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myView, nil];
newTabBarController.viewControllers = controllers; //this is the line that a get an error :Tread1:Program receive signal: SIGABRT
[myView release];
}
```

if i make a viewController subclass of UIViewController with Xcode and put it in the NSArray there is no problem but i want my view has screen.height - tabbar.height so i tryed make one programmatically.
Any help apresiated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- List item

UIView size

You can do this via Interface Builder.

Create the View you want for a given tab. Then go into the Attribute Inspector. The tab named "simulated metric" allow you to setup a TabBar (and even a NavigationBar).

- **SIGABRT**

  ```
  myView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,self.view.frame.size.height - newTabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height)];
  NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myView, nil];
  newTabBarController.viewControllers = controllers; //this is the line that a get an error :Tread1:Program receive signal: SIGABRT
  ```

This property is called viewControllers, not views.

The NSArray must contain UIViewController instances, or subclasses.

Thus, it better to define your View with IB (and configure look and feel to display TabBar, etc).
Then create your UIViewController with the method initWithNibName:bundle:, and put these instance into the newTabBarController.viewControllers.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer @NoTTC!
I tryed and your methods works fine!
Thus i've done something else before you answer my question.
I've made a subclass of UIViewController and in viewDidLoad i set its bounds!
This works to for me!
But again thanks for your time!